# C++ Singleton Destructor - Effect Having Delete oneInstance

Tags: c++, singleton, destructor

I have a question asking in a past paper, what is the effect of adding a destructor in Solo, which has the statement delete oneInstance, in its implementation.

What exactly is the effect of adding delete oneInstance?

```
class Solo
{
     public: 
          Solo* instance();
     private:
          Solo();
          static Solo* oneInstance();    
}
```

Comment: You have at least one typo here and beyond that we have no idea how you're using this class. Provide an [MCVE] and also tell us what _you_ think will happen, and what actually happens when you try it.

Comment: Simple answer - avoid singletons like plague and you will never have to worry about their behaviour. Over the time my position on sigletons shifted from 'almost never use' to 'never use'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get access violation at the end of your program. Assuming the instance is a static variable. The destructor will attempt to delete a static variable.